# Integral Estimation with Bernstein's Inequality

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

So the exercise is the following:

Let $g(x):[0,1] \to [0,1]$ a continuous function, we want to estimate the integral:

$\int_{0}^{1} g(x)\ \mathrm{d}x$

How many samples $g(X_n)$, with $X_n \sim \mathcal{U}_{[0,1]}$ are needed to estimate the integral with an error of $0.01$ with a probability of $0.99$ with:

$\frac{1}{n}(g(X_1) + g(X_2) + \ldots + g(X_n))$

The only hint is to use the Bernstein Inequality which says:

$\mathbb{P}(\frac{S_n}{n} > t) \leq \exp(\frac{nt^2}{2(v+Bt)})$

I hope someone can give me a hint on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathsf{E}g(X_i)=\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx$. Then, one may use [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#General_case_of_bounded_random_variables) to get
$$
\mathsf{P}\!\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i)-\mathsf{E}g(X_1)\right|>t\right)\le 2\exp\!\left(-2nt^2\right).
$$
Plugging $t=0.01$, the bound $2\exp(-2\cdot 10^{-4}n)\le (1-0.99)$ when $n\ge 26,\!492$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't $2 \exp(-2 \cdot 10^{-4}) \geq 0.01$ because we want that the approximated value should be in range of the integral by $0.01$

Comment: @herbert123 You're right.